# Xubuntu 16.04 LTS hibernation issue

Tags: xfce, hibernate

I have set my system to hibernate when closing the lid of my laptop. It did work for a couple of times (at resume, the LightDM chooser was displayed), but now it is no longer the case: at resume, the system reboots.

System settings (xfce) is still set to hibernate when closing the lid, though. 
Thanks in advance.